# Find a cell reference for a value in a R dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to find a way to search within a dataframe to return the column and row reference for multiple conditions.

```
#some data 
SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,25,5,8), LastYear=c(6,20,5,8))

 #code to find which row column TV is in which correctly gives row 3, col 1
 TVRef<-which(SalesData==("TV"), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

In the SalesData dataframe I would want to search for the dataframe (row, column) reference where Appliance = TV and where LastYear = 5.

I know how to search for a single item in R as per the above code but I don't know how to do this for multiple items. For this example I would want to return the result row 3, col 3 so I could then reuse this in further code to update the dataframe.

Is there anything anyone can suggest?

Comment: I don't understand what your expected result is for the column. When you say *I would want to search for the dataframe (row, column) reference where Appliance = TV and where LastYear = 5*, what is the output you expect? It the columns you want as the result are part of the input. Can you show your expected output for that input? And perhaps show how you would hope to do that input?

Comment: The expected output that I want is row 3 col 3. I then plan to use this to update the dataframe by doing: SalesData[3,3] <- 5000 (for example).

Comment: When you say "multiple items", do you mean one item is your example, *Appliance = TV and where LastYear = 5*, and you want to keep doing that with, e.g., `Appliance = Radio and where LastYear = 6, Appliance = TV and where ThisYear = 5, ...`. where you want multiple outputs? Or are you considering `Appliance = TV` as 1 item and `LastYear = 5` as item 2, and "multiple items" is combining those 2 with *"and"*?

Comment: But since *the column is part of the input*, it seems like the question is *which row meets these criteria (`Appliance == TV` and `LastYear == 5`), and which column is `LastYear`? (since `ThisYear` is part of the input)

Comment: My example of Appliance = TV and LastYear=5 is what i consider to be multiple items. I can find the row and column reference for a single item as per the example I gave in the code (TVRef)- it is row 3, column 1 for Appliance= TV but I dont know how to add the LastYear=5 element to this.

Comment: `&` is how you combine. `my_row = which(SalesData$Appliance == "TV" & SalesData$LastYear == 5)`. To update, since you already know the column name, you could use `SalesData[my_row, "LastYear"] = 5000`. Or, if you really want the column number, `my_col = which(names(SalesData) == "LastYear")`, then `SalesData[my_row, my_col] <- 5000`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a logical `and` (`&`) and pass multiple condition to row selector as follows:

```r
SalesData[c(SalesData$Appliance=="TV" & SalesData$LastYear==5),][[3]]
#[1] 5
```

An alternative using `with` can be done follows:

```r
with(SalesData, SalesData[Appliance=="TV" & LastYear==5,][[3]])
#[1] 5
```

This is a numeric output which you can do

```r
SalesData[c(SalesData$Appliance=="TV" & SalesData$LastYear==5),][[3]] <- 500
# To replace it with say 500.
```

Comment: You could also do SalesData[SalesData$Appliance=="TV", SalesData$LastYear==5] <- 500 however I am still curious about how to get the row and column number so I can re-use this in later code.

Comment: If you have another row with values `Appliance=TV, ThisYear=6, LastYear=5`, then your subsetting breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I like using dplyr functions that make it read pretty easily

```
SalesData<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), ThisYear=c(5,25,5,8), LastYear=c(6,20,5,8))


library(dplyr)


SalesData %>% 
  filter(Appliance == "TV" & LastYear == 5)
```